# How to write query to find duplicate combination of values in jumbled order in SQL Server table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I am having table values like as follow:

```
ID     Column1    
101     a    
101     b     
101     c    
102     aa   
102     bb   
102     cc    
103     b   
103     a      
103     c  
104     cc  
104     aa 
104     bb   
105     c  
105     a 
105     b
```

How to write SQL query to display result as shown below

```
ID    column1    
101    a    
101    b    
101    c        
102    aa    
102    bb    
102    cc
```

Comment: What have you tried?  e.g. ORDER BY & DISTINCT?  Can you show the exact output you want as it is unclear which repeated combination you are talking about

Comment: @Dijkgraaf, Please see the above table Column1 having a b c with same id i.e. 101 and a b c is repeated as b a c and c a b in different rows. So i want to write sql query to  display that jumbled combination.

Comment: So do you only want the distinct values in column1?   Do you want to show the ID?  If so which one? The lowest one if you have more than one row with the same column1?

Comment: OK, I withdraw my answer due to the question changing the output. Sorry -1 for wasting time by poorly posed question

Comment: sorry I am fresher that's why i am not able to post properly.

Answer (score 0):

If you group by column1 it will eliminate any duplicates for that. But then to display ID you will needs some sort of aggregate function such as MIN or MAX to show that, otherwise you will get an error.

```
SELECT MIN(ID) as ID, column1
GROUP BY column1
ORDER BY column1
```

Should result in

```
ID  column1
101 a
101 b
101 c
102 aa
102 bb      
102 cc
```

Comment: your query is not working its displaying different out put, not as shown above.

Comment: I want exact output what i given.

Comment: No, you said you wanted to remove the repeated combinations and did not give the final output.

Comment: ID 101 having a b c and ID 103 also having same combination like b a c, so i want to remove 103 and display 101 id values in column1 a b c.. Like that i want for all the combinations in that table.

Comment: Like I asked.  Please edit your question with those details and the exact output that you want.

Comment: So do you want it ordered by ID or by column?

Comment: @chakri I've updated the answer to match, but your sample does not match what you are saying

Answer (score 0):

There is more than one way to to do this but as the question is a bit ambiguous it is difficult to determine exact requirements from this but here's a couple of options:

**Order by the smallest id then by column1 alphabetically**

```
SELECT MIN(ID) as ID, column1 
GROUP BY column1
ORDER BY MIN (ID), column1
```

**Order by length of column1 and then column1 alphabetically**

```
SELECT MIN(ID) as ID, column1 
GROUP BY column1
ORDER BY LEN (column1), column1
```

Comment: its not working, i want exact output what i am displaying

Comment: Whats not working about it? I have both these outputting exactly what you have above, if LEN doesn't work try LENGTH?